# Local Kinesis : kinesalite + boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I want to setup boto3 kinesis client such that it makes use of kinesalite. So that I can work completely locally.

any insights?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an `endpoint_url` keyword argument to boto3 when initializing a client.

Assuming kinesalite is running on port 4567:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('kinesis', endpoint_url='http://localhost:4567')
client.list_streams()
```